# Debugging Windows 8 App using windbg

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windbg

I have a Windows 8 Application Store app that needs to be debugged on one of our lab machines.  The machines in the lab have windbg but do not have Visual Studio.  When I launch the EXE using windbg, I get a message that says "This application can be ran only in the context of an app container".

Is there anyway to get Windbg.exe to create the app container context?

Comment: Apparently there is a tool named [PLMDebug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj680085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) designed just for this purpose.

Comment: @Luke, post this as an answer, alone with instructions on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks Luke.

I can get the debugger to work after using plmdebug.exe.  But the break points can not be set.
When I set a break point, windbg says '*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for myapp.exe'
After executing the code where the break point is set, I can then set a break point.

Surly there is a better way?

Comment: To get rid of the "Unable to verify checksum" message, try the /release switch.

Answer (score 0):

WinDbg can attach pretty much to any running process. You can start your app in a regular way from the start screen and try to attach to it after that. I used this technique when debugging Win32 services.