# debugging C++ based app in windows 8

Tags: c++, windows, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, ida

I have a windows 8 metro style app which is made from C++.
(I am assuming this because there is no trail of HTML/JavaScript nor .net Assembly codes
beside some interface definition.  if there is a certain way to tell the developed environment of the app, please tell me)

inside the appx package, there is a 32bit exe file(PE).
this seem to be the main program but it can be only launched
through app container's context.

I want to debug this exe file with IDA pro(or olly).
since I can't start this exe file as a stand alone program
I tried to attach the running process with IDA.
but it seems IDA can not read process memory.(I am not sure)
so I tried to run IDA with administrator privilege.
now when I try to attach the running process, IDA just stops.

my question is "is it possible to debug a metro style app in windows 8
with IDA through attaching running process inside app container?"

or is it possible to run metro style app with IDA or olly from beginning?

is there some kind of new protection measure which prevents 
debugging apps in windows 8? or is it just my mistake or misconfiguration?

some advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485624/debugging-windows-8-app-using-windbg).

Comment: Not a duplicate as a question, but the answers would be related. It would just help if you could expand on your answer.